# Nginx single application config

Tags: angularjs, nginx

I'm writing an AngularJS single page application using nginx.

I just switched from apache to nginx, but I cant make my config file working.
I'm trying to rewrite everything to `index.html` to let Angular do the routing.

My `nginx.conf` is as follow:

```
server {
  index index.html;

  location / {
    expires -1;
    add_header Pragma "no-cache";
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

Is it possible to have my `nginx.conf` file in the project root like my `.htaccess` did?

Comment: I don't see why your `try_files` wouldn't work, but to answer your second question, no Nginx won't load config files randomly placed in directories.  Nor should it... this is a severe performance problem.  You can include whatever conf files you want for Nginx at start up.  For me, I place config files in an `nginx` directory in my code, and have Nginx include `projects/*/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You dont want nginx.conf in the project root and its not necessary. Also, you don't want direct changes to nginx.conf, you will instead want specific files for different websites in /etc/nginx/sites-available which you enable with a `ln` in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled.

As far as the config:

```
server {
 root /var/www/mysite/; #or whereever your site files are
 index index.html;

 location /{
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 }
}
```

You are missing the root portion which tells nginx where the site is located.